# ZegoCloud Logout Room Function Exists?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, zegocloud

I've tried:

```
zp.logoutRoom();
zp.stopPublishing(); 
zp.logout();
```

None are not valid SDK functions (despite ChatGPT's suggestions). And I can't think of other guesses.

I'd like to not resort to using a hack. Is there a logout function which I may call in the ZegoCloud CallKit SDK?